# Segfault when dereferencing a typedefed pointer passed from Rust to C

Tags: rust, segmentation-fault, ffi

I'm trying to write a plugin module in Rust for an existing C project. I've been writing the Rust bindings for the C project as I need them, and my latest one is throwing a segfault every time no matter how I try to interact with it.

Here's the C function signature I'm binding to:

```c
switch_xml_t switch_xml_open_cfg(const char *file_path, switch_xml_t *node, switch_event_t *params) 
{
    switch_xml_t xml = NULL, cfg = NULL;
    *node = NULL; // <-- seg-fault happens here
    assert(MAIN_XML_ROOT != NULL);

    if (switch_xml_locate("configuration", "configuration", "name", file_path, &xml, &cfg, params, SWITCH_FALSE) == SWITCH_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        *node = cfg;
    }
    return xml;
}
```

and here's the Rust binding and the invocation:

```rust
extern "C" {
    pub fn switch_xml_open_cfg(
        file_path: *const c_char,
        node: *mut switch_xml_t,
        params: *mut switch_event_t,
    ) -> switch_xml_t;
}
```

```rust
let mut cfg = switch_xml_t::default();
unsafe {
    libfreeswitch_sys::switch_xml_open_cfg(c_str!("skeleton_rust_raw.conf"), &mut cfg, std::ptr::null_mut());
}
```

I've tried passing the struct to C as:

- `&mut cfg`
- `Box::into_raw` pointer
- `&mut cfg as *mut`
- with `mem::forget` on it just in case.

I'm completely lost on how the pointer I'm passing in ends up null when it's dereferenced.

`switch_xml_t` is a type alias:

C:

```c
typedef struct switch_xml *switch_xml_t;
```

Rust:

```
pub type switch_xml_t = switch_xml;
```

For the following struct:

C:

```c
struct switch_xml {
    /*! tag name */
    char *name;
    /*! tag attributes { name, value, name, value, ... NULL } */
    char **attr;
    /*! tag character content, empty string if none */
    char *txt;
    /*! path to free on destroy */
    char *free_path;
    /*! tag offset from start of parent tag character content */
    switch_size_t off;
    /*! next tag with same name in this section at this depth */
    switch_xml_t next;
    /*! next tag with different name in same section and depth */
    switch_xml_t sibling;
    /*! next tag, same section and depth, in original order */
    switch_xml_t ordered;
    /*! head of sub tag list, NULL if none */
    switch_xml_t child;
    /*! parent tag, NULL if current tag is root tag */
    switch_xml_t parent;
    /*! flags */
    uint32_t flags;
    /*! is_switch_xml_root bool */
    switch_bool_t is_switch_xml_root_t;
    uint32_t refs;
};
```

Rust:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct switch_xml {
    pub name: *mut c_char,
    pub attr: *mut *mut c_char,
    pub txt: *mut c_char,
    pub free_path: *mut c_char,
    pub off: switch_size_t,
    pub next: *mut switch_xml_t,
    pub sibling: *mut switch_xml_t,
    pub ordered: *mut switch_xml_t,
    pub child: *mut switch_xml_t,
    pub parent: *mut switch_xml_t,
    pub flags: u32,
    pub is_switch_xml_root_t: switch_bool_t,
    pub refs: u32,
}
```

The Rust definition also implements `Default`:

```rust
impl Default for switch_xml {
    fn default() -> Self {
        switch_xml {
            name: std::ptr::null_mut(),
            attr: std::ptr::null_mut(),
            txt: std::ptr::null_mut(),
            free_path: std::ptr::null_mut(),
            off: 0,
            next: std::ptr::null_mut(),
            sibling: std::ptr::null_mut(),
            ordered: std::ptr::null_mut(),
            child: std::ptr::null_mut(),
            parent: std::ptr::null_mut(),
            flags: 0,
            is_switch_xml_root_t: switch_bool_t::SWITCH_FALSE,
            refs: 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Stargateur `switch_xml_t` is just a type-alias on `switch_xml`

Comment: @Shepmaster it's compiling as a dylib because it's just loaded at runtime by the C-project. i'm not sure how to make an MCVE without the big C-project i'm trying to write a plugin module for.

Comment: @Stargateur neither of those variables is causing a problem. that's in the C-code - which i don't have control of and works fine when using other plugin modules written in C.

Comment: updated. i'm not saying i know better than you, i just said the segfault is coming from the line after that which doesn't reference either of those 2 variables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190986/discussion-between-toadzky-and-stargateur).

Comment: Please note the *drastic* difference in code from your [original form](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55443152/1) to the [current form](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55443152/5). See how many things you didn't provide originally? Definitions of types are *important*! Definitions of macros are *important*! Please learn from your mistakes here and continue to improve your question asking skills. It will benefit you both here on Stack Overflow but more importantly everywhere else too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rust
pub type switch_xml_t = switch_xml;
```

Is not equivalent to

```c
typedef struct switch_xml *switch_xml_t;
```

This typedef hides a pointer. I really don't recommend this style — one reason why is why this question exists.

The Rust side should be:

```rust
#[allow(non_camel_case_types)]
pub type switch_xml_t = *mut switch_xml;
```

Comment: thanks. i don't like it either, i'm just writing the bindings to match the C code exactly

Comment: @toadzky Are you aware that automatic tool exist https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-bindgen ?

Comment: yeah, i tried using it but it didn't work. i'm not enough of a c or rust dev to understand what was going wrong

Comment: i'll try it again and see if i can get an error message